# Pyspark : Convert nested JSON struct to pyspark dataframe

Tags: json, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Is there an easy way to convert the below sample json into Pyspark dataframe ?

Input :

```json
{
"user": {
  "1": {
    "name": "Joe",
    "age": 28
  },
  "2" :{
    "name": "Chris",
    "age": 14
  },
  "3" :{
    "name": "Hally",
    "age": 21
  }
}
}
```

Expected output (dataframe):

```json
root
 |-- age: long (nullable = true)
 |-- id: long (nullable = true)
 |-- name: string (nullable = true)

+---+---+-----+
|age|id |name |
+---+---+-----+
|28 |1  |Joe  |
|14 |2  |Chris|
|21 |3  |Hally|
+---+---+-----+
```

Answer (score 2):

Read the JSON into dataframe, get the list of user `IDs` then create an array and explode it into multiple rows like this:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

json_example = '{"user":{"1":{"name":"Joe","age":28},"2":{"name":"Chris","age":14},"3":{"name":"Hally","age":21}}}'
df = spark.read.json(spark.sparkContext.parallelize([json_example]))

result = df.select(F.array(*[
    F.struct(F.lit(i).alias("id"), F.col(f"user.{i}.name"), F.col(f"user.{i}.age"))
    for i in df.select("user.*").columns
]).alias("users")).selectExpr("inline(users)")

result.show()
#+---+-----+---+
#| id| name|age|
#+---+-----+---+
#|  1|  Joe| 28|
#|  2|Chris| 14|
#|  3|Hally| 21|
#+---+-----+---+
```

---

Or simply using `stack` expression:

```py
from itertools import chain

df1 = df.select("user.*")

result = df1.selectExpr(
    f"stack({len(df1.columns)}," + ','.join(chain(*[(f"`{c}`", c) for c in df1.columns])) + ")"
).selectExpr("col1 as id", "col0.*")
```

Comment: This proved immensely useful as the json file I ingested did not have a main column name, it was all single row inputs (numbered) with nested json.  I was able to use .select("*").columns in conjunction with F.lit(i) to unpack.  Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can just chain with `DataFrame` and `apply` `Series`

```
out = pd.DataFrame(input).user.apply(pd.Series).rename_axis('id').reset_index()
Out[110]: 
  id   name  age
0  1    Joe   28
1  2  Chris   14
2  3  Hally   21
```